# How this array passed to the other function just by passing size and without passing the array

Tags: arrays, c

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmVmR.png)

and i got the correct output as well.
but I don’t know how it worked without passing the array and i just passed the size only. tried many other ways but couldn’t ,so tried this simple way and succeeded. but how come?it's not even a global variable. is it because i used same name in both function.?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getArray(int);
void displayArray(int);
int main(void) {
    int arr[100],size;
    printf("Enter the size of the array\n");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    getArray(size);
    displayArray(size);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
void getArray(int size){
    int arr[100],i;
    printf("Enter elements of the array \n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }

}
void displayArray(int size){
    int i,arr[100];
    printf("Array is \n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        printf("%d\t",arr[i]);
    }
}
```

[output-tried many set of datas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhI6V.png)

[tried this by adding *printf helloword* in between two functions and again got the correct answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuzyL.png)

Comment: Because data happened to remain in memory at the expected places. If you insert `printf("%s\n", "Hello World!");` between `getArray(size);` and `displayArray(size);` it should expose the undefined behaviour, by trashing some of those memory locations.

Comment: Still I got the answer.

Comment: Make the arrays small, say `int arr[5]` with 5 inputs.

Comment: yes, that didn’t work. when it’s a smaller size array, it shows wrong values.

Comment: An acceptable outcome of undefined behavior is your program "working." Compile with warnings on.

Comment: yeah, I tried. it still worked. it only got wrong when I used a variable in between those 2 functions. else worked and got the output.

Comment: cc -Werror -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic arrayWithTwoFunctions.c. tried this only, any other way to find the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, `main` allocated memory on the stack for its variables.

```
----------------
|   int size   |
|   (4 bytes)  |
----------------
|              |
| int arr[100] |
| (400 bytes)  |
|              |
----------------
|     main     |
----------------
```

When you called `getArray`, it allocates memory for its variable on the same stack and proceeds to write to the array:

```
----------------
|   int size   |
|   (4 bytes)  |
----------------
|              |
| int arr[100] |        While memory is allocated
| (400 bytes)  |        the kernel won't give it
|  [1,2,3,4]   |        to a different process.
|              |
----------------
|   getArray   |
----------------
|   int size   |
|   (4 bytes)  |
----------------
|              |
| int arr[100] |
| (400 bytes)  |
| [values,...] |
|              |
----------------
|     main     |
----------------
```

After `getArray` finishes execution, it frees the memory used by its variables. It **DOES NOT** wipe it, it tells the kernel, that other processes can use it. And the values stay there as is.

```
                                                      ----------------
    int size                                          |   int size   |
    (4 bytes)                                         |   (4 bytes)  |
                                                      ----------------
                                                      |              |
  int arr[100]     Memory gets freed -                | int arr[100] |
  (400 bytes)      The kernel can allocate it         | (400 bytes)  |
   [1,2,3,4]       to another process.                |  [1,2,3,4]   |
                   But it doesn't get wiped -         |              |
                   the values stay in memory.         ----------------
                                                      | displayArray |
----------------          Unless you use memset()     ----------------
|   int size   |          `arr` will have the         |   int size   |
|   (4 bytes)  |          value of the variable       |   (4 bytes)  |
----------------          that was previously         ----------------
|              |          stored there.               |              |
| int arr[100] |                                      | int arr[100] |
| (400 bytes)  |                                      | (400 bytes)  |
| [values,...] |                                      | [values,...] |
|              |                                      |              |
----------------                                      ----------------
|     main     |                                      |     main     |
----------------                                      ----------------
```

When you call `displayArray` it allocates memory for its variables in the same location as getArray did.

So it is very important to make sure that your variables (especially arrays of structs) don't contain any values.
`memset(&<variable>, 0, sizeof(<variable>));`


I hope that helped!